# Trying to change react Carousel into class component

Tags: reactjs

i have react carousel in the functional component , i am trying to change that component in to class component.. can any one help on this..

this is the link of code sand box....https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-cookies-fvm80?file=/src/App.js

functional component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ItemsCarousel from 'react-items-carousel';
 
export default () => {
  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState(0);
  const chevronWidth = 40;
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: `0 ${chevronWidth}px` }}>
      <ItemsCarousel
        requestToChangeActive={setActiveItemIndex}
        activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
        numberOfCards={2}
        gutter={20}
        leftChevron={<button>{'<'}</button>}
        rightChevron={<button>{'>'}</button>}
        outsideChevron
        chevronWidth={chevronWidth}
      >
        <div style={{ height: 200, background: '#EEE' }}>First card</div>
        <div style={{ height: 200, background: '#EEE' }}>Second card</div>
        <div style={{ height: 200, background: '#EEE' }}>Third card</div>
        <div style={{ height: 200, background: '#EEE' }}>Fourth card</div>
      </ItemsCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is your issue/error "what missing" (Your component is already a class component)?

Comment: i have added functional component , can you help me on that to convert into class component

Comment: not about the copy paste code...thanks for your reply ...i got idea for answer from the Józef Podlecki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap jsx in `render()` method, change `useState` hook to destruct from `this.state`, and create function for setting state.

**Example**

```
export default class carousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      activeItemIndex:0
    };
  }

  setActiveItemIndex = (value) => {
    this.setState({ activeItemIndex: value });
  }

  render() {
    const { activeItemIndex } = this.state;

    const chevronWidth = 40;
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: `0 ${chevronWidth}px` }}>
        <ItemsCarousel
          requestToChangeActive={this.setActiveItemIndex}
          activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
          numberOfCards={2}
          gutter={20}
          leftChevron={<button>{"<"}</button>}
          rightChevron={<button>{">"}</button>}
          outsideChevron
          chevronWidth={chevronWidth}
        >
          <div style={{ height: 200, background: "#EEE" }}>First card</div>
          <div style={{ height: 200, background: "#EEE" }}>Second card</div>
          <div style={{ height: 200, background: "#EEE" }}>Third card</div>
          <div style={{ height: 200, background: "#EEE" }}>Fourth card</div>
        </ItemsCarousel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i have made some changes in your code...thanks very much